# French meaning of "dire pour <quelque chose>

Tags: grammaire

I was watching a french cop movie (Rogue City on netflix) and one character says "Helene m'a dit pour le flic". Is the preposition pour typical usage in this context? Would it be incorrect to say "Helene m'a dit du flic"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That use of *dire pour* is a spoken, idiomatic form in French.

**dire pour** means: to **tell someone about something or something**.

So, **Hélène m'a dit pour le flic** ***means*** **Hélène told me about the cop**.

When two people are talking about others or what others have said:

D'autres exemples:

- Oui, Jean était très malin mais **tu ne m'a pas dit pour** Marie.
- Suzanne était présente sur le lieu du crime, mais **on ne m'a pas** **dit pour** Hélène.
- Les bagnoles étaient complètement cramées mais **on ne m'as pas dit pour les vélos**.

This: "Helene m'a dit du flic" would be part of a longer form:

- Helene m'a dit du flic qu'il [whatever it was when discussed between the two speakers]. Just "Helene m'a dit du flic" is not idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

Oui, ce serait incorrect de dire ‘Hélène m’a dit du flic’ (it doesn’t make sense)
Vous pouvez retrouver l’usage de cette préposition dans d’autres contextes similaires:

- ‘Il m’a dit pour hier… tu vas bien?’
- ‘Elle m’a informé pour l’événement de demain’

**Par contre:**

- Il m’a dit **du** mal de toi. (pas de ‘pour’ ici)

‘Helene m’a dit du flic’ aurait été correct si il y avait une suite, comme: ‘Hélène m’a dit du flic qu’il n’était pas sympa…’